# Regex to extract string between quotes

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to extract a string between two quotes, and I thought I had my regex working, but it's giving me two strings in my GroupCollection, and I can't get it to ignore the first one, which includes the first quote and ID=

The string that I want to parse is

> Test ID="12345" hello

I want to return 12345 in a group, so that I can manipulate it in code later.  I've tried the following regex: http://regexr.com/3bgtl, with this code:

```
nodeValue = "Test ID=\"12345\" hello";
GroupCollection ids = Regex.Match(nodeValue, "ID=\"([^\"]*)").Groups;
```

The problem is that the GroupCollection contains two entries:

> ID="12345
>
> 12345

I just want it to return the second one.

Comment: you need to print group 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use positive lookbehind operator:

```
GroupCollection ids = Regex.Match(nodeValue, "(?<=ID=\")[^\"]*").Groups;
```

You also used a capturing group (the parenthesis), this is why you get 2 results.

Comment: This worked perfect, thanks for the quick response.  I was using groups, as I believe in some cases there was more than one instance of the ID, and it's actually being passed into a replace later.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to accomplish this.  I like named capture groups for readability.

Regex with named capture group:

```
"(?<capture>.*?)"
```

And your code would be:

```
match.Groups["capture"].Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is totally OK and is the most efficient from all the solutions suggested here. Capturing groups allow the quickest and least resource-consuming way to match substrings inside larger texts.

All you need to do with your regex is just access the captured group 1 that is defined by the round brackets. Like this:

```
var nodeValue = "Test ID=\"12345\" hello";
GroupCollection ids = Regex.Match(nodeValue, "ID=\"([^\"]*)").Groups;
Console.WriteLine(ids[1].Value);
// or just on one line
// Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(nodeValue, "ID=\"([^\"]*)").Groups[1].Value);
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/EMYcd0)

Please have  a look at [Grouping Constructs in Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Grouping constructs delineate the subexpressions of a regular expression and capture the substrings of an input string. You can use grouping constructs to do the following:
>
> - Match a subexpression that is repeated in the input string.
> - Apply a quantifier to a subexpression that has multiple regular expression language elements. For more information about quantifiers, see [Quantifiers in Regular Expressions][3].
> - Include a subexpression in the string that is returned by the [Regex.Replace][4] and [Match.Result][5] methods.
> - Retrieve individual subexpressions from the [Match.Groups][6] property and process them separately from the matched text as a whole.

Note that *if you do not need overlapping matches*, capturing group mechanism is the best solution here.